# Couldn't determine an appropriate version of runtime to run

Tags: iis-express, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, dnvm

I just finished upgrading to beta4. My code compiles successfully with no errors/warnings but I am unable to launch my web api hosted in IIS Express (by hitting `F5`). I get the following error:

> **Couldn't determine an appropriate version of runtime to run.** See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517742 for more information.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't
>   determine an appropriate version of runtime to run. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517742 for more information.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Couldn't determine an appropriate version
>   of runtime to run. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517742
>   for more information.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags
>   hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception
>   appDomainCreationException) +303
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Couldn't determine an appropriate version
>   of runtime to run. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517742
>   for more information.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9940016
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101 System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +261
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.57.0

Here is the output from `dnvm list`:

> C:\src\web-api-skeleton [master]> dnvm list
>
> Active Version Runtime Architecture Location Alias
>
> ---
>
> - 1.0.0-beta4 clr x64 C:\Users\dpeden.dnx\runtimes default
>     1.0.0-beta4 clr x86 C:\Users\dpeden.dnx\runtimes
>     1.0.0-beta4 coreclr x64 C:\Users\dpeden.dnx\runtimes
>     1.0.0-beta4 coreclr x86 C:\Users\dpeden.dnx\runtimes
>     1.0.0-beta4-11566 clr x86 C:\Users\dpeden.dnx\runtimes

I have also tried explicitly setting the runtime (`Use Specific Runtime` on the Debug tab of the project properties) which appears not to have any effect.

I did not have this issue prior to upgrading to VS 2015 RC and beta4 from VS 2015 CTP 6 and beta3.

How do I resolve it?

Thanks.

[Cross reference on ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/post/5904227.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was a simple problem. After reading https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/3, I realized that I had changed `aspnet50` to `dnx46` whereas it should have been `dnx451`. After making that change in all of my `project.json` files, my issue was resolved.

Snippet:

"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {}
},