# Running asp.net 5 website in IIS 10 throws Couldn't determine an appropriate version of runtime to run error

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, iis-10

I've just created a new ASP.NET 5 web application in Visual Studio 2015. It runs fine under IIS Express, but when I create a site in IIS 10 on Windows 10 and point it at the `wwwroot` folder I get a YSOD:

> Couldn't determine an appropriate version of runtime to run

This has been discussed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081380/couldnt-determine-an-appropriate-version-of-runtime-to-run) but in my case the `project.json` file looks ok:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

As with the other post, here's the output of `dmvm list`:

> ```
> Active Version     Runtime Architecture Location                     Alias
> ------ -------     ------- ------------ --------                     -----
>        1.0.0-beta5 clr     x64          C:\Users\Simon\.dnx\runtimes
>        1.0.0-beta5 clr     x86          C:\Users\Simon\.dnx\runtimes
>        1.0.0-beta5 coreclr x64          C:\Users\Simon\.dnx\runtimes
>        1.0.0-beta5 coreclr x86          C:\Users\Simon\.dnx\runtimes
> ```

All of the dependencies are `beta5` in `project.json`

Has anyone else got this to work with IIS on Windows 10?

Comment: I haven't been able to try windows 10 yet, but did you try the console approach and run dnu publish?  I know I had worlds of trouble with tiny adjustments that were overlooked or low-documented, and forcing the runtime with the --runtime option helped.  EDIT <-- sorry, I meant to say I had adjustment woes in VS 2015 and the file system publish option

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed after doing some research  (I have battled a lot of the ASP .Net5 hurdles at my own job -- I had a difficulty with this error between beta 5 and 6...  was fighting architecture differences.  One thing that got me on track was I ran the

`dnvm use {version u need}` and did `dnu restore` on command line.  I noticed you have no default on the dnvm list output, so it may be trying to publish multiple runtimes to your project output directory.  I'd investigate ./approot/runtimes/...  and see how many different runtimes there are; there should only be one.